# C# - Expecting "{" in if statement but got "("

Tags: c#, if-statement, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm writing a program for school that emails the user once a certain device detects the moisture level is above a certain value. I don't know C/C#/C+++ (I have to write it in C# since the main program is in C#), I do know python however so using the main program combined with my Python knowledge I was able to make an if statement. The issue is, when ran it gives the error expected "{" but got "(". Since this isn't an issue in Python I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Any help?
NOTE: Emails, passwords, and names have been removed for my security.

```
/// Adding time (In progress. Lines 2, 3, 12, 26)

// Send email if plant is too moist
if (MoistureValue > 2) {
{
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
{
    Port = 587,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testemail@email.com", "RandomPasswordRandomNumber"),
    EnableSsl = true,
   
};

smtpClient.Send("exampleemail@email.com", "My name", "Plant Moisture", "Your plant is above its reccomended moisture go check on it!.");
}
}
// Send email if plant is too dry
if (MoistureValue < 2) { 
{
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
{
    Port = 587,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testemail@email.com", "RandomPasswordRandomNumber"),
    EnableSsl = true,
    
};
    
smtpClient.Send("exampleemail@email.com", "My Name", "Plant Moisture", "Your plant is a little dry, go water it!");
}
}
```

Comment: did you know that _one_ set of brackets per if is enough; and that proper indentation makes your code moch more readable and syntax errors easier to spot? the error doesn't seem to be in this piece of code, though.

Comment: Thanks, that's on me. Definitely could have better indentation but the part about brackets I didn't know.

Comment: In Python, you use indentation to indicate blocks of code. In C-family languages, you use `{curly-bracket-pairs}`. A block of code (say the code associated with an `if` statement) is demarcated with open-close curley brackets. So for example: `if (boolean-condition) { Func1(); Func2(); }` works.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The issue is when I do that this line of code 
```smtpClient.Send("exampleemail@email.com", "My name", "Plant Moisture", "Your plant is above its reccomended moisture go check on it!.");
```
Goes blue in VSC indicating something is wrong.

Comment: Research project :(, I was going to write it in Python BUT the source I got the materials from wrote the main program in C# so there's not much I could do other than use what I know, which is little. Source also isn't emailing back right now considering its the holidays so here I am.

Comment: *Goes blue in VSC indicating something is wrong* - never used VSC for C#, but I do not think this is correct/accurate. I'm quite sure that "wrong" things get a red wiggly underline in VSC; they do in JS and this C# [screenshot I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0msPm.png) would appear to support that  - post a screenshot of your VSC

Answer (score 0):

In programming we strive to reduce repetition. Your code can be reduced to:

```
if (MoistureValue != 2) {

    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587) {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testemail@email.com", "RandomPasswordRandomNumber"),
        EnableSsl = true,
    };

    var msg = MoistureValue > 2 ? 
      "Your plant is above its recommended moisture go check on it!." : 
      "Your plant is a little dry, go water it!";
    
    smtpClient.Send("exampleemail@email.com", "My Name", "Plant Moisture", msg);
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your braces are imbalanced. And you should get the case in which nothing will happen out of the way first. So maybe you go with.

```
// When everything is okay, do nothing.
if (MoistureValue == 2) return;

var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    {
        Port = 587,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testemail@email.com", "RandomPasswordRandomNumber"),
        EnableSsl = true,
    };

var message = MoistureValue < 2 ? "Your plant is a little dry, go water it!" : "Your plant is above its reccomended moisture go check on it!.";

smtpClient.Send("exampleemail@email.com", "My name", "Plant Moisture", message);
```

Comment: there are a few superfluous ones, but no, they are _not_ imbalanced.